# Error when entering search center for some users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, error, language, search-center

I recently encountered an issue: when entering our Search center logged in as a user with alternate language set, I receive the following error message:

> "Literal content (' ') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection'".

When logged in as admin (default language) the Search Center works just fine.

The error message indicates that there are a misplaced "&nbsp;" somewhere in the code; but I've no idea where that would be, as far as I know sharepoint uses the same files for both default and alternate languages.

Any suggestions?

[image: Error message]

EDIT: Seems like the alternate language has nothing to do with it, the problem occurs for all users who are not admin or owner. Still no clue; if there were anything wrong in the code, would it not affect admins and owners as well?

Comment: Have you recently edited your master page, CSS files or template for search?

Comment: I use default master page, the css file was last edited a month ago. The Search center was set up several months ago, last week I edited the web parts / refinements. No coding though.

Comment: However, this was the first time I tried to access the Search center from a non-admin user login, so I don't know whether it worked before editing the search center, or before setting up alternate languages. Though it works fine also for non-admin users with default language set.

Comment: A few options then: 
1) Check your source code for the &nbsp; string  2) If you worked with the web part/refinements in designer, look at the code there for either the &nbsp; string or html code where you are missing quote marks (ie td class=box instead of td class="box") 3) look at the ULS logs to see what part precisely is being called.

Comment: Update: Seems like the alternate language has nothing to do with it, the problem occurs for all users who are not admin or owner. Also tried several browser without luck. I did not find anything in the code, however I cannot access the search center in SharePoint Designer - but if it was a &nbsp; in code, wouldn't it affect the owners/admin too? Sadly ULS logs seem not to be available for Sharepoint Online :(

Comment: Have you checked that all masterpage, pagelayouts (whatever custom that might required major check-ins) on your site are checked in/published?